# Installing jre locally in windows app directory

Tags: java, windows, jar

I have a question about deploying windows application with java module.

I have windows application with several modules. One of these modules is written in java and is packaged as jar-archive. And if there's need for using this module, the application ask jre to start execute this jar.
For this time during application installation it's initialized jre installation.

I would like to understand the following.
Is it possible to install during application installation silently install jre in the application directory. So it jre copy could be used by the application.

I'm talking about structure like this:

```
/app
/app/jre
/app/modules/myModule.jar
```

So if it's needed to run myModule.jar I could do it with java from app/jre/bin ?

I saw something like that at Spark messenger (http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/). This application uses its own jre, which is installed at /Spark/jre/. But as I understand, this application is written in java and builded as a windows distributive using install4j.

I tried to find the answer to my question, but maybe I'm doing something wrong, I always find a solution of creating an exe-wrapper for jar file.

I would like to know about possibility to deploy application with installing jre locally in application folder.

Answer (score 1):

You could ideally have used Java Web Start in the past.
Currently, you can use javapackager.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javapackager.html

The javapackager command allows developers to create standalone native install bundles that do not require a separate JRE installation. The native options include: installer, image, exe, msi, dmg, rpm, and deb.

This is ideal for desktop applications, where the user may not have their own JRE installed and just wants the program to run.  It may not be appropriate for server-based applications where an administrator would want full control over the environment.

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_web_start_in_or

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'll try to explain my situation. There's an app with a lot of modules. One module is written in java and packaged as a jar. Another modules can run it if they need it. So I would like to use not system jre but locally copy of jre without change of invoking exe instead of jar.

Comment: Can you explain the sentence, "So I would like to use not system jre but locally copy of jre without change of invoking exe instead of jar."

Comment: For this time, jre is installing on system during the application installation. I would like to know if there's possibility to install a jre to application folder during installation, not as system jre with path, regedit things, just for my application.

Comment: You could manually install the JRE. 
For that 
1. You will have to zip the installed JRE 
2. Unzip the same in your application directory.
3. add appropriate PATH, JAVA_HOME & CLASSPATH variables to the script to start the application.

Comment: do you know, is it legal to have an app distributive with jre zip inside it? Is it legally to deploy jre like this?

Comment: Yes, JRE is free to use and bundle. javapackager should also be doing something similar.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'll try to explore this question as you recommend.

Comment: Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html

Answer (score 0):

In your /app/jre/bin folder there should be an executable binary called java. So in your folder /app/modules you can run

```
/app/jre/bin/java -jar myModule.jar
```

That should work.

Comment: my question is how to create my app/jre? Is it a proposed procedure for this? If I just copy jre files and copy it in local folder during application installation - is it legal?

Comment: Sorry I have no clue about the licensing issues (*cough* never cared about...). To be sure, just download the JRE installer from Oracle, it will present you some sort of license you have to agree to before installing. And installing it in your /app/jre folder will work fine. After that, you can always copy it from there.

I know of applications (e. g. DB-Visualizer) that are shipped with a JRE, so it seems alright to do it.